# Copying a file form one drive to multiple drive won't work in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, file, cmd

I need to **copy a directory form one source form multiple destination**. For example, i copied a file from my **C:** drive and paste it into **many external drives like E:,F:,G:...etc**. For this process i used the following code,

```
set src=%~1

:Loop
    shift
    set dest=%~1
    if "%dest%"=="" goto :EOF
    xcopy "%src%" "%dest%" /E
goto Loop
```

i saved this code snippet as **.bat in system32 folder**. Then i use this command as

```
C:\Windows\System32>mcopy C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\Screenshot E: F:
```

i executed this command in my command prompt it executed successfully.

Then i tried to implement this command in my java application.

My java code is,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MultipleCopy{

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String exe_Cmd = "c:/Windows/System32/mcopy C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot E: F:";
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C",
                exe_Cmd });
        Process pro;
        try {
            pro = p.start();
            InputStream is = pro.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("IO Exception" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

it was executed without any errors but the files won't copied.

My eclipse IDE's console's output is:

```
C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>set src=C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>shift

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>set dest=E: 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>if "E:" == "" goto :EOF 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>xcopy "C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot" "E:" /E 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>goto Loop 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>shift

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>set dest=F: 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>if "F:" == "" goto :EOF 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>xcopy "C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot" "F:" /E 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>goto Loop 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>shift

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>set dest= 

C:\Users\FSSD\IndigoWorkSpace\Multi_Copy>if "" == "" goto :EOF
```

In this, what is my mistake, how can i get the exact output. Reply me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Would it not be easier to use Java to copy the files, instead of having to hassle around with command line? The new java.nio Classes introduced with Java 7 would make you use case trivial to implement using `Files.copy()`. Also your solution would be portable as opposed to only working on your PC.

Comment: @pushy: My aim is to copy the files form source to Multiple destination. this concept can achieved from Files.copy()?

Comment: Sure, why not. First you copy the file to the first destination, then to the second destination, and so on, just like you do in your batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters to ProcessBuilder may not contain spaces, instead of

```
String exe_Cmd = "c:/Windows/System32/mcopy C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot E: F:";
```

you need

```
String[] pars = {"cmd.exe", "/C","c:/Windows/System32/mcopy","C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot","E:","F:"};
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(pars);
```

But I still would rather use a Java solution, like I suggested in the comments already ;-)

Comment: is there any possible to convert the copy code snippet into dos file instead of .bat file.

Comment: Does it work when you execute `cmd.exe /C c:/Windows/System32/mcopy C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot E: F:` on the command line? If not, try `String exe_Cmd = "\"c:/Windows/System32/mcopy C:/Users/FSSD/Desktop/Screenshot E: F:\"";`

Comment: it will works in command line, but won't work in java application

Comment: good news, i covert the script into exe (default DOS command exe) it works fine and thanks for your effort. Thanks a lot.